# How to save list output as csv file

Tags: python, list, csv

Using python 3.5
I have a output file in the form of :

```
result = 
[{'alt': '',
  'company_id': 309,
  'confidence': 0,
  'person_id': 17591,
  'person_image_url': '',
  'person_name': 'abc'},
 {'alt': '',
  'company_id': 309,
  'confidence': 0,
  'person_id': 20298,
  'person_image_url': '',
  'person_name': 'def'},
 {'alt': '',
  'company_id': 309,
  'confidence': 0,
  'person_id': 20301,
  'person_image_url': '',
  'person_name': 'ghi'}]
```

How do I save this as a CSV file with the format below:

```
alt company_id confidence person_id person_image_url person_name
      309          0        17591         ''            abc   
      309          0        20298         ''            def
      309          0        20301         ''            ghi
```

Comment: There are lots and lots of csv questions already on SO.  While your desired data format looks more fixed-width than csv to me, you don't seem to have mentioned what problem you encountered when you tried anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
df.to_csv('result.csv', index=False, sep='\t')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the package `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
print(df)
df.to_csv('result.csv', index=False, sep=';')
```

Comment: This does the trick for me. Thanks guys                                                   import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(result)
df.to_csv('result.csv', index=False, sep=',')